# Find documents with boolean value on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have a mapping which has a boolean field:

```
{
   ...

   "bool_field": {
      "type": "boolean"
   },
   ...
}
```

How possible to find documents on a boolean value without specifying the name of the field?
I tried one of the following, but without result:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easy, by default, because [`boolean` fields are not `include_in_all` (the `_all` field is used by default by `query_string`)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5502#issuecomment-38421898). This explains why your query doesn't work.

What you can do, though, is to use [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) to create your own [custom `_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html) and use that in the `query_string`.

Something like this:

```
    "bool_field": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "copy_to": "_all_booleans"
    }
```

And then

```
"query_string": {
  "default_field": "_all_booleans", 
  "query": "true"
}
```

or

```
"query_string": {
  "query": "_all_booleans:true"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This is a great solution in my opinion, but I forgot to specify elastichsearch version is 1.6. So for my unfortunately did not fit. I will issue a duplicate version that your response has been approved.

Comment: It should work with 1.6... I haven't specifically tested it in 1.6, but with 1.7.5 I don't see a problem.

Comment: Ok, I will recheck again

Comment: Just tested with 1.6.0 and it works. If it's not working for you can you provide more details about it?

Comment: Yes, really works, I made a mistake in the syntax of the query. Excuse me. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Detected unclear situation in this decision, if a query has any value other than "false", then there will always be found records that have a value of "true". For example: 

"query_string": {
        "default_field": "_all_booleans",
        "query": "aaa"
      }

. As result will always be found record with the value "true"...

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html#boolean - `False values

false, "false", "off", "no", "0", "" (empty string), 0, 0.0`. `True values

Anything that isn’t false.`

Comment: ahh, that's it. :) Thanks for the quick response!
Wondering if without changing the mapping, this problem is decided? In the sense of search documents with boolean value

Comment: I don't it will work, because you don't want to mention the name of the field for query_string. This means it will use _all or something you specify. So, either way you need to change the mapping or specify the field name in `query_string`.

Comment: Clear. Thank you for your comprehensive answer!